# Do people with Asperger syndrome have two left brains?

Tags: aspergers, brain-development

I have heard that people with Asperger syndrome have a problem with the right brain, but it increases the ability of the left brain. In other words, AS people has two left brains; the second left brain replaces the right brain. Is this true?

Answer (score 10):

Most neuroscientists have dropped the *right brain-left brain differentiation* because cross-over of functions at multiple levels is now so widely recognized. So your understanding of *two left brains* is not current (if it ever was).

Comment: So is there any difference between the brain in left and the brain in right?